# ¿Cómo puedo limitar de manera correcta el cuerpo de una solicitud HTTP en golang?

Tags: go

Actualmente estoy construyendo un servidor web en golang usando simples librerias como `gorilla/mux` o `net`, y ya que lo que estoy construyendo es una API, me gustaria que el cuerpo de la solicitud no sea demasiado grande ya que podria ocasionar que el servidor gaste demasiados recursos. He buscado formas de evitar un cuerpo de solicitud muy grande, como usar `net/http.MaxBytesReader` o simplemente las respuestas de [esta pregunta en stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74484230/is-this-code-ok-to-avoid-a-big-http-request-golang/74484550). Pero me pasa exactamente lo que dice en esa misma pregunta, si el cuerpo
de la solicitud es mayor al maximo permitido obtengo este mensaje de mi navegador:

```
The connection was reset

The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
```

Entonces, ¿qué puedo hacer para no recibir ese mensaje?

Por ejemplo, si en `nginx` limitas el maximo cuerpo de la solicitud y el cuerpo enviado supera el limite, el servidor no crashea, no sale algun mensaje de error como el que yo obtengo, ¿hay alguna forma de hacer algo similiar en golang?

Comment: lo que dice el navegador es lo correcto, el servidor cerro la conexion ( leyó hasta donde pudo y cerró ) en nginx y otros servidores el "error" suele ser [400](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) o [413](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/413) en el rfc dice que si al servidor no le gusta lo que esta recibiendo puede comunicarselo al cliente y el cliente debe dejar de enviar https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230#section-6.5 "A client sending a message body SHOULD monitor the network connection..."

Comment: 2/ asi que tendrías que implementar que si el buffer se llena ( leiste el max permitido ) le mandas al cliente un "eee pará (400/413)" y luego cerrar la conexion ( o cerrar la escritura asi el cliente recibe el mensaje y deja de enviar siendo el cliente encagado de cerrar como describe en seccion 6.6 )

Comment: @aloMalbarez ¿Y como seria eso en código?

Comment: que resultados te da [MaxBytesReader](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#MaxBytesReader) ? segun entiendo implementa el mecanismo del rfc "If possible, it tells the ResponseWriter to close the connection after the limit has been reached." osea cierra el write y dispara el "A client that receives a "close" connection option MUST cease sending requests on that connection and close the connection after reading the response message containing the "close";" con un err [body too large](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.4:src/net/http/request.go;l=1150)

Comment: @aloMalbarez Obtengo justo ese error. ¿Como puedo mostrar otra cosa en lugar de solo ese error?

Comment: estaba leyendo esto https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.4:src/net/http/server.go;l=550;drc=ea14d1b6e1167159dfc8408073ef411c3cf1d7e0 y buscando https://www.google.com/search?q=golang+requestBodyLimitHit parece q es cuestion de revisar si hay error nomas https://stackoverflow.com/a/28292505/1423096, interpreto que usas el reader y si hubo err falla el parse ( se setea un flag ) ahi cambias el response